Can someone explain to me how the first-child or nth-child works?
I want to style only the first div inside the experience-container, but it is styling all the divs inside the experience container. How can use :first-child or :nth-child to do this?
This is my code:
    <article v-for="(item, index) in experiencies" :key="index"
        class="experience-container d-flex flex-column justify-content-start align-items-center w-100 p-3 pt-4 pb-4 rounded-3 ">
        <div class="h-100 d-flex flex-column gap-4">
            <div class="title mt-4">
                <h3 class="mb-0">{{ $t("Experience." + item.company + ".company") }}</h3>
                <p class="mb-0">{{ $t("Experience." + item.company + ".job") }}</p>
                <p class="mb-0 duration">{{ $t("Experience." + item.company + ".duration") }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="summary w-auto">
                <p class="mb-1">{{ $t("Experience.Experience1.description") }}</p>
                <div class="d-flex flex-wrap gap-2">
                    <span v-for="(element, index) in item.tags" :key="index"
                        class=" tag bg-secondary bg-opacity-50 text-primary rounded-5 text-nowrap">
                        {{ $t("Experience.Experience1.tags[" + element + "]") }}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



.experience-container div:first-child {
    width: 65%;
}


Could you make the question more clear? It seems the first div in .experience-container already includes all the content.

I like to use a red border while debugging CSS so I can see what's affected. Check MDN for documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child

:first-child

Selects: The first child element of its parent.
Example:
ul li:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}

(Styles the first <li> inside every <ul> with bold font.)

:nth-child(n)

Selects: The nth child element of its parent, where n can be a number, keyword (like odd or even), or formula (like 3n).
Examples:
p:nth-child(2) {
  color: blue;
}
/* Styles the second <p> element */

li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
/* Styles all odd-numbered <li> elements */

div:nth-child(3n) {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
/* Styles every third <div> element */



These pseudo-classes allow you to target elements based on their position within their parent.
To style only the first <div> inside the first .experience-container using CSS:
.experience-container:first-of-type > div:first-child {
    width: 65%;
}

This targets the first .experience-container and applies styles specifically to its first <div> child.
